# How to remove few fields from JSON array response using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am getting a JSON response like below:

```
[  
{
"id": "1",
"name": "Abhi",
"pan": "ABC",
"bg": "O+"  
},  
{
"id": "2",
"name": "Ashish",
"pan": "XYZ",
"bg": "AB+"  
},
.
.
.
]
```

and I want to remove the "pan" and "bg" field from all elements of the array in the final response.Like below:

```
[
{
"id": "1",
"name": "Abhi"
},
{
"id": "2",
"name": "Ashish"
},
.
.
.
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `map` function.

```js
const data = [
{"id": "1", "name": "Abhi", "pan": "ABC", "bg": "O+"},  
{"id": "2", "name": "Ashish", "pan": "XYZ", "bg": "AB+"}
]
const newArr = data.map(item => { return {
  id: item.id,
  name: item.name
}})
console.log(newArr)
```

`map` function always generate a new array. You can go for `forEach` and `delete` method to update the actual array.

```js
const data = [
  {"id": "1", "name": "Abhi", "pan": "ABC", "bg": "O+" },  
  {"id": "2", "name": "Ashish", "pan": "XYZ", "bg": "AB+"}
];

data.forEach((item) => { delete item.pan; delete item.bg });

console.log(data);
```